# Replace key in array from external file and write it back

Tags: php, arrays, file, replace, file-get-contents

I have an array in a file and I want to change a value from this and write it back to file like the original file.

My file with the array:

```php
return [
    'modules' => [
        'test-module1'      => 1,
        'test-module2'      => 1,
    ],
];
```

I want to replace a value (the numbers) and write it back like this style to a file with PHP (when it's possible).

E.g. I want to disable `test-module1` and set key to `0`. What is the best way. I've no plan at this time.

EDIT: I know how to change the key but I don't know how to write it back to the file.

Comment: This seems like a poor way to format a data file. It would be better to use JSON or `serialize()` format.

Comment: Use `var_export` function

Comment: You dont want to do this. You want to have a little think about what you are doing and come up with a better way of doing it. Suggest you have a think about what @Barmar suggested

Comment: is it `*.php` file?

Comment: @RiggsFolly the best way I see is to do it with json or yml.

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest yes it is

Comment: @AbraCadaver You are strarting to worry me?????

Comment: @RiggsFolly: Me too :-( ....

Comment: @AbraCadaver Still someone liked your answer. ?? :(

Comment: @no2br3ak JSON Yea, now your cookin with gas

Comment: @RiggsFolly: Well, apart from not being the best format to store data, it at least works now.

Comment: @AbraCadaver Well undelete it then and we can UV it

Comment: @RiggsFolly:  I did maybe refresh page.

Comment: @RiggsFolly That was already clear to me but i'am a magento lover and i want to do it like magento 2 :D

Comment: @no2br3ak Your sexual preferences are totally irrelivant here. We are an equal oportunities helper. :)

Comment: @RiggsFolly yes I know :D ok so I do it in json ;) Thanks for your help and feedback :)

Comment: @RiggsFolly: haha! and just like that they changed orientation!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do this with JSON. However, if you are tied to this format, it returns an array.  Just include, modify and write:

```
$result = include('path/to/file.php');
$result['modules']['test-module1'] = 0;
```

But it would be difficult to get that format.  You would get the other array format with `var_export()`:

```
file_put_contents('path/to/file.php', 'return ' . var_export($result, true) . ';');
```

Yields:

```
return array (
  'modules' =>
  array (
    'test-module1' => 0,
    'test-module2' => 1,
  ),
);
```

However, `json_encode($result, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);` will yield:

```
{
    "modules": {
        "test-module1": 0,
        "test-module2": 1
    }
}
```

Then you can use `file_get_contents()` and `json_decode()` from there.  No need to `return`.

Comment: Oh maybe not. The result of an include is true or false

Comment: Not when you `return` a value.  http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php Example #5

Comment: Oh yea, my testing mistake. Silly Billy Me.